Can Netanyahu use sovereign or diplomatic immunity as his defence to evade the arrest warrant issued by the ICC?
I listened to some experts, and I think the answer is no. But I'm not sure why.
By the way, I'm not sure if it's more relevant "sovereign immunity" or "diplomatic immunity". Answers are welcome for each case.
EDIT: I did some research, and even if this question is answered, I don't think Netanyahu would ever be arrested due to the Hague Invasion Act, which basically states that if Netanyahu was brought to the Hague to stand trial, the US would invade the Netherlands.

In what manner?: Simply Netanyahu's lawyer goes to the ICC and uses the sovereign immunity as his defence in order to avoid standing trial. By whom?: By Netanyahu.

The Hague invasion act authorizes the president to use "all means necessary and appropriate" -- it does not prevent a president from deciding than an invasion of the Netherlands would be inappropriate, as any sane president would.  Among other things, this would put the US at war with the rest of NATO.

I expect the practical effect of the warrant is that no country that would arrest Netanyahu under the ICC warrant, will invite him to their country. Heads of government don't travel unless they've co-ordinated that travel with their destination. So the immediate effect is a travel ban, unless he can arrange an exception. There was some attempt (I don't remember from whom) in South Africa to change the national law so that they didn't need to arrest Putin under an ICC warrant. But the outcome was that Putin remotely addressed BRICS when it was there.

.. and it's true that many countries, including for that matter Israel, have previously arrested people without co-operation from the territory they are arresting them in. I don't know that anyone's ever tried that for a head of government visiting a neutral third-party. It would be... bold. By which I mean I suspect it's a clear act of war ;-) And he's hardly going to turn up in the Netherlands on a commercial flight just to find out whether he gets arrested. He evades the warrant not by any form of immunity, but by not going anywhere that would execute it.

@bestofthebeast: for what it's worth, al-Bashir (former head of state and government of Sudan) is still under ICC indictment. In the 10 years between his indictment and the coup that removed him, his lawyer never went to the ICC and got the charges dismissed on grounds of immunity. This doesn't as such prove it's impossible, but certainly it suggests that the ICC does not consider prosecuting a head of government to be an absurdity.

@phoog It would not, of course, put the US at war with the rest of NATO - it would merely authorize the rest of NATO (most of which relies on the US for their protection) to take whatever measures they feel appropriate, which, in this case, would likely be a sternly worded speech.

@Therac NATO responding militarily to a military invasion of the Netherlands by the United States is at least as likely as the US invading the Netherlands in the first place.

@SteveJessop: Given that the Rome Statute expressly contains Article 27, “Irrelevance of official capacity”, with “official capacity as a Head of State or Government, a member of a Government or parliament, an elected representative or a government official shall in no case exempt a person from criminal responsibility under this Statute”, I see no reason why ICC should consider prosecuting a head of government to be an absurdity…

@phoog Of course, but traditionally the US doesn't go to war, it just acts in other countries as if it owns them. A simple drone strike or black ops hit isn't anything the US has never done before.

Sovereignty
An arrest warrant would be executed by a country party to the Rome Statute should Netanyahu be present in such a country.
Such country would be exercising its own sovereign authority, as it committed to do, in the execution of the arrest warrant.
Netanyahu would have no argument about how such country should exercise its sovereign authority.
Diplomatic / head-of-state immunity
The question of whether heads of states who are not party to the Rome Convention maintain any immunity before international tribunals is an unsettled question in international law. The ICC views there to be a  "absence of a rule of customary international law recognising Head of State immunity before international courts in the exercise of proper jurisdiction." States have been less clear. Even those who have said they will comply with the arrest warrant have not expressly reasoned through  the head-of-state immunity.

See this answer and my comments under it for more details on the ICC’s jurisprudence on head-of-state immunity.
